# What is the difference between mode and class in R?

Tags: r

I am learning R (I started just this week), and I've been struggling with the concepts of typeof, mode, storage.mode and class. I've been searching up and down (official R documentation, StackOverflow, Google, etc.), and I haven't been able to find any clear explanation of the difference between these. (A few [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881662/the-class-and-mode-of-a-matrx) [and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052158/in-r-why-is-matrix-a-class-but-a-vector-is-not) [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/mode-class-and-type-of-r-objects) answers have not really helped clear me up.) Finally (I hope), I think I understand it, and so my question is to verify if my understanding is correct.

**mode vs storage.mode:** [mode and storage.mode are basically the same thing](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mode.html), except for a tiny difference in how the "single" datatype is handled.

**mode vs typeof:** [Very similar, except for a few differences](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mode.html), most notably that both (typeof "integer" and "double") = (mode "numeric"); and both (typeof "special" and "builtin" = (mode "function").

**class:** Class is based on R's object-oriented class hierarchy. I'm having a hard time finding this graphically laid out, but the best I've been able to find is this diagram:

[image: rpy2 robjects package]

*(If anyone can point me to a more accurate R class hierarchy, I'll replace it.)*

Although the class names don't correspond exactly with the results of the R class() function, I believe the hierarchy is basically accurate. My understanding is that **the "class" of an object--that is, the result of the class() function--is the root class in the hierarchy.** So, for example, "Vector" is not a root class and so it never shows up as the result of the class() function. The root class might rather be "StrVector" ("character") or "BoolVector" ("logical"). In contrast, "Matrix" is itself a root class; hence, its class is "matrix".

Apparently, R supports multiple inheritance, and so some objects can have more than one class.

**typeof/mode/storage.mode vs class:** This is what was hardest part for me to understand. My understanding now is this: typeof/mode/storage.mode (which I will refer to henceforth simply as **"mode") is basically the most complex datatype that an R object can hold as one of its values**. So, for example, since matrixes, arrays and vectors can hold only one vector datatype, their mode (that is, the most complex datatype they can hold) is typically numeric, character or logical, even though their class (their position in the class hierarchy) is something completely different.

Where this gets most interesting (that is, confusing) is with objects like lists. A mode of "list" means that each value in the object can itself be a list (that is, an object that can hold diverse datatypes). Thus, regardless of if the class itself is "list", there are multiple objects (e.g. data frames) that can contain diverse values, and whose mode is therefore "list", even if their class is something else.

So, in summary, my understanding is:

- typeof/mode/storage.mode (almost the same thing) is basically the most complex datatype that an R object can hold as one of its values; whereas
- class is an object's object-oriented classification according to the R class hierarchy.

**Is my understanding accurate? If not, could someone please give a more accurate explanation?**

Comment: So your notion of class needs to be adjusted first. There is no THE R object system. The class attribute pertains to the S3 method dispatch system, but there are many others. The graph you found describes some basic data type structures in the R language but that doesn't really have anything to do with an object oriented system at all.

Comment: @Richard Scriven, if my understanding is correct, then the answers I'm looking for is a simple yes. However, if my understanding is mistaken, then the answers I'm looking for should point out my misunderstandings. So, it's not a simple yes/no. Actually, I considered the option to answer my own question (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), but since I'm not certain about the answer, I am not bold enough to do that.

Comment: @joran, could you please expand that comment to a full answer? That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many years of R, I now feel confident enough to answer this question that I asked in my first week of learning R eight years ago! I am currently taking Richie Cotton's DataCamp course on [Object-Oriented Programming with S3 and R6 in R](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/object-oriented-programming-with-s3-and-r6-in-r/). He provides a lovely example that I adapt here to demonstrate the differences between these four kinds of "datatype" in R:

```
# objects of various datatypes
list(
  an_integer_vector = rpois(24, lambda = 5),
  a_numeric_vector = rbeta(24, shape1 = 1, shape2 = 1),
  an_integer_array = array(rbinom(24, size = 8, prob = 0.5), dim = c(2, 3, 4)),
  a_numeric_array = array(rweibull(24, shape = 1, scale = 1), dim = c(2, 3, 4)),
  a_data_frame = data.frame(int = rgeom(24, prob = 0.5), num = runif(24)),
  a_factor = factor(month.abb),
  a_formula = y ~ x,
  a_closure_function = mean,
  a_builtin_function = length,
  a_special_function = `if`
) |> 
  purrr::map(\(.o) {
    c(
      class = class(.o), 
      typeof = typeof(.o), 
      mode = mode(.o), 
      storage.mode = storage.mode(.o)
    )
  })
#> $an_integer_vector
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>    "integer"    "integer"    "numeric"    "integer" 
#> 
#> $a_numeric_vector
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>    "numeric"     "double"    "numeric"     "double" 
#> 
#> $an_integer_array
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>      "array"    "integer"    "numeric"    "integer" 
#> 
#> $a_numeric_array
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>      "array"     "double"    "numeric"     "double" 
#> 
#> $a_data_frame
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#> "data.frame"       "list"       "list"       "list" 
#> 
#> $a_factor
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>     "factor"    "integer"    "numeric"    "integer" 
#> 
#> $a_formula
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>    "formula"   "language"       "call"   "language" 
#> 
#> $a_closure_function
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>   "function"    "closure"   "function"   "function" 
#> 
#> $a_builtin_function
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>   "function"    "builtin"   "function"   "function" 
#> 
#> $a_special_function
#>        class       typeof         mode storage.mode 
#>   "function"    "special"   "function"   "function"
```

`mode` and `storage.mode` are compatibility holdovers from the S language, R's predecessor. `storage.mode` is a low-level datatype and `mode` is a slightly higher-level datatype. But they are not practically useful in R, unless you are interacting with both R and S code, which no one I know does. So, I will not discuss them further. Of the four kinds mentioned here, only `class` and `typeof` are pertinent for contemporary R programming.

`typeof` reveals the most fundamental datatype for R objects, going all the way down to the underlying C language datatypes in which R is implemented. So, it indicates how the variable is stored in the computer memory in terms of the lowest-level datatypes available in R. An object can only have one `typeof` type. The different possibilities can be found from `help(typeof)`:

```
A character string. The possible values are listed in the structure TypeTable
in ‘src/main/util.c’. Current values are the vector types "logical", "integer", 
"double", "complex", "character", "raw" and "list", "NULL", "closure" 
(function), "special" and "builtin" (basic functions and operators), 
"environment", "S4" (some S4 objects) and others that are unlikely to be seen 
at user level ("symbol", "pairlist", "promise", "language", "char", "...", 
"any", "expression", "externalptr", "bytecode" and "weakref").
```

`class` mainly refers to the datatype from the perspective of R's S3 object-oriented system. (I just learnt that R has historically had at least nine different object-oriented systems; S3, inherited from S, is the most pervasively used.) From my current understanding, a `typeof` type is fundamental to the very nature of an object whereas the `class` type is a kind of label that is ascribed to describe an object. A key difference between the two is that `typeof` is read-only whereas `class` is read-write. That is, we cannot directly change an object's `typeof` type; we must convert the underlying object into an object of a different type; indeed, there is no assignment allowed for `typeof`. In contrast, `class` allows assignment, which, for basic datatypes, converts the variable from one datatype to another. So, a variable's `typeof` can be changed by indirectly converting it by changing its `class`:

```
some_numbers <- c(1L, 2L, 3L) # 'L' added to create integers, not doubles
some_numbers
#> [1] 1 2 3
typeof(some_numbers)
#> [1] "integer"
class(some_numbers)
#> [1] "integer"

typeof(some_numbers) <- 'double'
#> Error in typeof(some_numbers) <- "double": could not find function "typeof<-"
class(some_numbers) <- 'character'
some_numbers
#> [1] "1" "2" "3"
typeof(some_numbers)
#> [1] "character"
class(some_numbers)
#> [1] "character"
```

Another important difference is that an object can have many `class` classes whereas it can only have one `typeof` type. So, let's try something funky:

```
some_numbers <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L) # 'L' added to create integers, not doubles
some_numbers
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
typeof(some_numbers)
#> [1] "integer"
class(some_numbers)
#> [1] "integer"

class(some_numbers) <- c('mango', 'character', 'integer')
some_numbers
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "mango"     "character" "integer"
typeof(some_numbers)
#> [1] "integer"
class(some_numbers)
#> [1] "mango"     "character" "integer"

is.integer(some_numbers)
#> [1] TRUE
is.character(some_numbers)
#> [1] FALSE
```

This example shows some key differences between `typeof` and `class`:

- An object may have only one `typeof` type but it may have multiple `class` classes.
- Whereas `typeof` is fundamental to the object, `class` is nothing more than an attribute (although a special one).
- `class` classes can be anything we want, whether valid `typeof` types or not (e.g., 'mango' in the example).
- If an object is assigned multiple `class` classes that are valid `typeof` types, then the most fundamental one according to [the hierarchy of `typeof` types](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#vector-basics) is the one used for its true `typeof` type.
- The built-in `is.*` functions correspond to the `typeof` type, not directly to the `class`. So, we could not fool `is.character()` into thinking that our manipulated variable was a character vector. The character `class` for the final version is merely an attribute label, not the true `typeof` type of the object.

Answer (score 30):

'mode' is a mutually exclusive classification of objects according to
their basic structure.  The 'atomic' modes are numeric, complex,
character and logical.  Recursive objects have modes such as 'list' or
'function' or a few others.  An object has one and only one mode.

'class' is a property assigned to an object that determines how generic
functions operate with it.  It is not a mutually exclusive
classification.  If an object has no specific class assigned to it, such
as a simple numeric vector, it's class is usually the same as its mode,
by convention.

Changing the mode of an object is often called 'coercion'.  The mode of
an object can change without necessarily changing the class.  e.g.

```
> x <- 1:16
> mode(x)
[1] "numeric"
> dim(x) <- c(4,4)
> mode(x)
[1] "numeric"
> class(x)
[1] "matrix"
> is.numeric(x)
[1] TRUE
> mode(x) <- "character"
> mode(x)
[1] "character"
> class(x)
[1] "matrix"
```

However:

```
> x <- factor(x)
> class(x)
[1] "factor"
> mode(x)
[1] "numeric"
```

At this stage, even though `x` has mode numeric again, its new class,
`factor`, inhibits it being used in arithmetic operations.

In practice, mode is not used very much, other than to define a class
implicitly when no explicit class has been assigned.

Answer (score 15):

I hope the following examples are helpful. In particular, have a look at the last two examples.

```
x <- 1L
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- 1
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- letters
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- TRUE
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- cars
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- cars[1]
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- cars[[1]]
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- matrix(cars)
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- new.env()
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- expression(1 + 1)
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- quote(y <- 1 + 1)
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))

x <- ls
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
```

The results are:

```
[1] "integer"      "numeric"      "integer"      "integer"
[1] "numeric"      "numeric"      "double"       "double" 
[1] "character"    "character"    "character"    "character"
[1] "logical"      "logical"      "logical"      "logical"
[1] "data.frame"   "list"         "list"         "list"      
[1] "data.frame"   "list"         "list"         "list"      
[1] "numeric"      "numeric"      "double"       "double" 
[1] "matrix"       "list"         "list"         "list"  
[1] "environment"  "environment"  "environment"  "environment"
[1] "expression"   "expression"   "expression"   "expression"
[1] "<-"           "call"         "language"     "language"
[1] "function"     "function"     "function"     "closure"
```

The last example shows you a case where typeof() != storage.mode().

Comment: Thank you. Can you please give example in a same way for integer

Comment: Great explanations with nice code to illustrate differences.  This tells me that... MOST of the time... for introspection or type discovery... use the `class()` and `typeof()` functions. These give me the object class / type information and storage information.  The `mode()` function is pretty useless, because the storage.mode() specifics (e.g., double, integer) tell me that it is numeric.  Bottom line for me: 1) use `class()` first, then `typeof()` to get the most relevant object information.   I was using `mode()`.

Answer (score 6):

Just for better readability.

I hope the following examples are helpful. In particular, have a look at the last two examples.

```
x <- 1L
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "integer"      "numeric"      "integer"      "integer"

x <- 1
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "numeric"      "numeric"      "double"       "double" 

x <- letters
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "character"    "character"    "character"    "character"

x <- TRUE
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "logical"      "logical"      "logical"      "logical"

x <- cars
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "data.frame"   "list"         "list"         "list"   

x <- cars[1]
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "data.frame"   "list"         "list"         "list"      

x <- cars[[1]]
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "numeric"      "numeric"      "double"       "double" 

x <- matrix(cars)
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "matrix"       "list"         "list"         "list"  

x <- new.env()
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "environment"  "environment"  "environment"  "environment"

x <- expression(1 + 1)
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "expression"   "expression"   "expression"   "expression"

x <- quote(y <- 1 + 1)
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "<-"           "call"         "language"     "language"

x <- ls
print(c(class(x), mode(x), storage.mode(x), typeof(x)))
[1] "function"     "function"     "function"     "closure"
```

Credits - @SHUAICHENG WANG

Answer (score 6):

simply put, the only really useful ones are `class()` and `typeof()`

- `class` can be described as the 'container' of an object, an attribute that makes this object behave externally with functions that take this particular 'type' of object as argument
- `type` is what this object is made of inside the container, the 'type' of underlying values

good obvious example:

```
x <- as.Date('2010-01-01')
class(x) # Date
typeof(x) # double
unclass(x) # 14610

attr(x, 'tz') <- 'CEST'
attributes(x)$class # "Date"
attributes(x)$tz # "CEST"
```