# In R, does "integer" type inherit from "numeric" type or not?

Tags: r

I'm trying to check the input I'm getting from a user to make sure it's the correct type. In this case, I'm fine with either `integer` or `double` as long as it's some kind of number.

I'm using `checkmate::check_class()` like so with the following results:

```
> checkmate::check_class(4, "numeric")
[1] TRUE
> checkmate::check_class(as.integer(4), "numeric")
[1] "Must inherit from class 'numeric', but has class 'integer'"
```

My confusion is because numerous sources on the internet (notably [this one](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/base-types.html) from Hadley, in section 12.3.1) appear to be saying that both `integer` and `double` *do* in fact inherit from `numeric`. So why does this fail?

Sidenote: `check_class()` says it uses `inherits()` under the hood so I tried using it explicitly and got the same results.

```
> inherits(4, "numeric")
[1] TRUE
> inherits(as.integer(4), "integer")
[1] TRUE
> inherits(as.integer(4), "numeric")
[1] FALSE
```

Thanks in advance for any help and clarification.

Comment: [Relevant](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/35445112/what-is-the-difference-between-mode-and-class-in-r). In `checkmate`'s check_class, it's checking for class which is integer: `class(as.integer(4))`. I don't think it checks inheritance per se. Checking `4` is checking using a vector of mode numeric while `as.integer` explicitly specifies a class integer object. Check out these lines in the source code `ord = inherits(x, classes, TRUE)
    w = wf(ord == 0L)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really to do with the [difference between `mode` and `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445112/what-is-the-difference-between-mode-and-class-in-r). When  you use `as.integer(4)`, you're explicitly creating an object of class `integer`. `inherits` checks class inheritance and therefore `inherits(as.integer(4),"numeric")` will return `FALSE` because it is not class `numeric`.

**`as.integer(4)` is still a `numeric` object but R's `inherits` checks only `class`es not `mode`s which is unlike what you would have expected in terms of inheritance.**

> inherits indicates whether its first argument inherits from any of the classes specified in the what argument. If which is TRUE then an integer vector of the same length as what is returned. Each element indicates the position in the class(x) matched by the element of what; zero indicates no match. If which is FALSE then TRUE is returned by inherits if any of the names in what match with any class.

Now, looking at the source code of `checkmate::check_class`, it is essentially doing the same thing(**checking inheritance of class not mode**):

```
function (x, classes, ordered = FALSE, null.ok = FALSE) 
{
    qassert(classes, "S+")
    qassert(ordered, "B1")
    qassert(null.ok, "B1")
    if (is.null(x) && null.ok) 
        return(TRUE)
    ord = inherits(x, classes, TRUE)
    w = wf(ord == 0L)
    if (length(w) > 0L) {
        cl = class(x)
        return(sprintf("Must inherit from class '%s', but has class%s '%s'", 
            classes[w], if (length(cl) > 1L) "es" else "", 
            paste0(cl, collapse = "','")))
    }
```

**Why does the first work?**

Use checkmate::check_class(4,"numeric"), it correctly returns `TRUE` because:

```
 class(4)
[1] "numeric"
```

I think `inheritance` here is not used in the way you might have expected because it seems to stop at "one level"(just the class and not mode):

```
mode(as.integer(4))
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful. "unlike what you would have expected in terms of inheritance" is definitely accurate. I'm still not clear on what `inherits()` is really doing, or more specifically why it's called "inherits". It doesn't seem to involve inheriting classes from a base or parent class like I had expected. But that is just a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: I think if you really want inheritance, the s4 system provides a more intuitive and more "complex" inheritance approach.