# Difference between class() and typeof() in R?

Tags: r

Both `class()` and `typeof()` appear to return very similar outputs on some vectors and lists.

`?typeof`:

> typeof determines the (R internal) type or storage mode of any object

and `?class`

> R possesses a simple generic function mechanism which can be used for an object-oriented style of programming. Method dispatch takes place based on the class of the first argument to the generic function.

In practice, what are the differences between the two?

Comment: This question has already been answered. Check 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445112/what-is-the-difference-between-mode-and-class-in-r

Comment: Side note: I found this small chapter helpful: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/base-types.html

Comment: In practice, you'll be usually interested in the class on an object.

Comment: @Roland class() is what I use day to day, but tbh, I don’t think I’ve ever actually used typeof()

Comment: Me neither, I usually use `str(obj)`, `unclass(obj)` or `dput(obj)` to study the structure (and storage mode) of objects. However, I could imagine applications where I'd want to check the storage mode programmatically.